# In fulleditmode/designmode, how can I refer to the currently selected <div> using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a text editor using iframe and designmode/texteditable in JavaScript. I know that the standard way to select and change text is to use execCommand, but there's no execCommand that works for some of the functionality I want. So what I'm trying to do is, write some code that will tell JavaScript to get the current div in the iframe (where the cursor is located), and then tell it to change the div's CSS style. Does anyone know how I can refer to the currently selected div in Javascript or JQuery, with or without execcommand?

I've tried various versions of execcommand, as well as the standard javascript for selecting elements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to reference the document's [`activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement). Here's an example:

```js
editor.onkeydown = function () {
  console.log(document.activeElement);
};
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Edit my text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This selected the whole body but I wanted to be more specific, so ended up using getSelection().focusNode.